# Query Mongodb for Sub - Subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a `mongodb` document with the following format

```
{
    inner : [{
        name : "I don't this",
        anotherName: "I don't want this",
        wayInside : [{
            something : 'skip this',
            somethingElse : 'skip this',
            someArray: { 
                 stuff:'I want this',
                 morestuff: {
                   field3: "Show me",
                   field2: "Show me",
                   field3: [{ "show everything from here down" }]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to get out a the first record in `wayInside` like this

```
result: [{ 
                 stuff:'I want this',
                 morestuff: {
                   field3: "Show me",
                   field2: "Show me",
                   field3: [{ show everything from here down }]
 }]
```

I don't want to match on anything I just want all the data inside of moreStuff with the one field ("stuff" in this example) from the property above the morestuff property.  How would I do this?

I've tried aggregate and find...but haven't even come close...

Comment: I keep saying this, but over-embedding is the root of all evil. I'd strongly suggest using a cleaner data structure, either through references or maybe by inverting the logical coupling between the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`aggregation pipeline`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$inner"},
    {$unwind: "$inner.wayInside"},
    {$project: {
        stuff: "$inner.wayInside.someArray.stuff", 
        morestuff: "$inner.wayInside.someArray.morestuff"
    }}, 
    {$project: {stuff: 1, morestuff: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

Output

```
{ 
    "stuff" : "I want this", 
    "morestuff" : { 
        "field3" : [ "show everything from here down" ],     
        "field2" : "Show me" 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the projection parameter in the MongoDB shell, which is also available in its platform-specific drivers.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

So you would want something like:

```
db.inner.find({
    "name": "I want this"
}, {
    "name": true,
    "wayInside": true
});
```